# How to get a long press time on UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift2

I want to get a long press time on UIView when touchesEnded method is called.

I was looking for a property like 'time' or 'duration' in UIEvent but I couldn't find.
How can I do?

(I'm creating a game, I want to change a graphic size in response to long press time. e.g. let size = 20 * long_press_sec )

Environment:
Xcode7.0.1
Swift2.0

Comment: Another way except Duncan's solution is use touchesBegan and touchesEnded. But is some kind of complicated. I Believe best way is recognizer.

Comment: @Mehdi hosseinzadeh, Thank you for your comment.
It seems the best way to use recognizer. Your advice was helpfull for me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can get that info automatically on a standard long press gesture recognizer. You can set the time that it takes to fire with the `minimumPressDuration` property, but then it fires.

It's been a while since I've done anything complex with gesture recognizers, but after looking at the docs a little bit, here's how I think you'd get gesture time:

Check the gesture recognizer's state in calls to your action method. When you see the `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` state
record the time (and remember to add in the minimum gesture time, since your method won't fire until the minimum long press duration has passed).

Your action method will be called again with a state of `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` when the gesture finishes. At that point you should be able to calculate the total duration of the gesture.

### EDIT:

Starting from @ManikandanD's code:

```
var longPressBeginTime: NSTimeInterval
var gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer = 
  UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressed:")
gesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.2
self.Your_View_name.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

func longPressed(longPress: UIGestureRecognizer) 
{
    if (longPress.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) 
    {
       let gestureTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() -
         longPressBeginTime + longPress.minimumPressDuration 
       println("Gesture time = \(gestureTime)")
    }
    else if (longPress.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began) 
    {
      println("Began")
      longPressBeginTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
Oh, I see, using `UIGestureRecognizer` is the best way in this case.
I tried it and it has gone well, thank you very much!

Comment: If you want your graphic to change size continuously as the user presses on it then a long press gesture recognizer probably won't work and you'll need to use `touchesBegan`/`touchesEnded`.